# jquery on click not fired

Tags: jquery, input, text, event-handling

like from jquery-documentation i want to fire click-event like this:
Documentation:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

My Html-Construction is:

```
<tr class="myRow">
    <td class="myName">GFK /CFK</td>
    <td id="start" tabindex="1">
        <input maxlength="4" id="GFK /CFK-4_1!2" name="10725|2|0.68">
    </td>
    <td tabindex="2">
        <input maxlength="4" id="GFK /CFK-4_1!3" name="|" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and i want to reach to fire any event, when i do something in my input-text element:

```
$("tr.myRow td").on("click", "input[type='text']", function(){

    alert("CONTENT: " +     $(this).val());

});
```

Comment: What you're saying is that every time you click an `<input>` you want to alert its value?

Comment: Is the DOM loaded when you bind the listener? Assuming the `<tr>` is inside a `<table>`, the DOM is loaded, jQuery is loaded (did you check for errors in the console?), the click event does fire for every click on the second `<input>`, because only it has a `type="text"`.

Comment: input[type='text'] doesn't have a click event. Use .change instead.

Comment: @AmanKhanna Of course text fields have click events.

Comment: @Xufox 
Thats a good point. jQuery event-selector above is present everytime. But my HTML-construction will be rendered after DOM has been loaded wihtin: 

$( document ).ready{
    createTableDynamicly();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am using jQuery 1.11.1 and for this version i should use instead of "on" a function "live".

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("tr.myRow td").on("input", "input[type='text']", function(){
    alert("CONTENT: " +     $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `click` events are not `input` events.